# PHP Elasticsearch returning 0.0 for all scores

Tags: php, laravel, elasticsearch

I have an AWS Elasticsearch instance provisioned and seeded with a bunch of band names. If I query it via cURL on the command line I get a nice set of weighted results including scores:

```
curl -XGET 'search-mydomain-3gk2dsu32xfb5ar4kcfablqjla.us-west-2.es.amazonaws.com:80/index/bands/_search?q=Burn'

{"took":13,"timed_out":false,"_shards":
    {"total":5,"successful":5,"failed":0},"hits":
        {"total":17,"max_score":5.6469817,"hits":
            [{"_index":"index","_type":"bands","_id":"17554","_score":5.6469817,"_source":{"id":17554,"band":"Burn Witch Burn"}},
                  {"_index":"index","_type":"bands","_id":"30730","_score":4.617216,"_source":{"id":30730,"band":"Burn Halo"}},
```

However, when I use the elasticsearch/elasticsearch PHP package in my composer.json file:

```
   "require": { 
       "elasticsearch/elasticsearch": "^2.2"
```

That completely ignores the _scores:

```
       "hits" => array:3 [
      0 => array:5 [
        "_index" => "index"
        "_type" => "bands"
        "_id" => "2890"
        "_score" => 0.0
        "_source" => array:2 [
          "id" => 2890
          "band" => "Jack Starr's Burning Starr"
        ]
      ]
      1 => array:5 [
        "_index" => "index"
        "_type" => "bands"
        "_id" => "8381"
        "_score" => 0.0
        "_source" => array:2 [
          "id" => 8381
          "band" => "D. Greenfield & J.J. Burnel"
        ]
      ]
```

I can't for the life of me figure out how to get the _scores to be reflected.

I'm trying to do this in a Laravel 5.3 application using laravel/scout, so the query is straight forward:

```
App\Band::search('Burn')->get();
```

but the problem lies in the elasticsearch package as I'll dump the results in there and see the 0.0 scores.

Kevin

Comment: Possibly related ~ https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-php/issues/48

Comment: Can you post the code where you make your query.

Comment: Edited my original post to reflect how the query is made.

Comment: The github issue mentioned above is for a different package :